# How to disable the write protection of the USART mode register?

Tags: serial, arduino-due

I have a device which transmits USART with inverted polarity, and I would like to read data from it with the help of an Arduino. I use an Arduino Due, which has a SAM3X processor, so it should be able to invert the polarity without any external hardware.

The settings accessible from the Arduino SDK are minimalistic, `Serial.begin()` only allows to set the baudrate and start/parity/stop, nothing else.

In the SAM3X datasheet I found the "USART Mode Register", `US_MR`, which dedicates bit 23 (`INVDATA`) to invert the polarity.

[image: USART Mode Register]

Although it seems not to be documented anywhere, I found in a forum that to access the `US_MR` register, I have to use `UART->UART_MR`. I can read that register but cannot change it. The SAM3X datasheet mentions that this register might be write protected, and that the write protection can be cleared in the `US_WPMR` register.

However, the Arduino SDK doesn't seem to know about this register. I tried several possibilities,

```
US_WPMR
UART_WPMR
WPMR
UART->US_WPMR
UART->UART_WPMR
UART->WPMR
```

None of which are known.

The string `WPMR` is nowhere to be found in any of the files in my Arduino installation folder.

**EDIT:**

Interestingly, [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/arduino-ide/+/f876b2abdebd02acfa4ba21e607327be4f9668d4/hardware/arduino/sam/cores/arduino/UARTClass.cpp) for the UART class doesn't contain any reference to the WPMR. It just sets the required configuration registers without bothering with it.

```
void UARTClass::begin( const uint32_t dwBaudRate )
{
  // Configure PMC
  pmc_enable_periph_clk( _dwId ) ;
  // Disable PDC channel
  _pUart->UART_PTCR = UART_PTCR_RXTDIS | UART_PTCR_TXTDIS ;
  // Reset and disable receiver and transmitter
  _pUart->UART_CR = UART_CR_RSTRX | UART_CR_RSTTX | UART_CR_RXDIS | UART_CR_TXDIS ;
  // Configure mode
  _pUart->UART_MR = UART_MR_PAR_NO | UART_MR_CHMODE_NORMAL ;
  // Configure baudrate (asynchronous, no oversampling)
  _pUart->UART_BRGR = (SystemCoreClock / dwBaudRate) >> 4 ;
  // Configure interrupts
  _pUart->UART_IDR = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  _pUart->UART_IER = UART_IER_RXRDY | UART_IER_OVRE | UART_IER_FRAME;
  // Enable UART interrupt in NVIC
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(_dwIrq);
  // Enable receiver and transmitter
  _pUart->UART_CR = UART_CR_RXEN | UART_CR_TXEN ;
}
```

However, when I try to change `UART_MR`, it remains the same.

Comment: Did you try `USART0->US_WPMR`? Couldn't you add it? The register mapping offset is 0xE4 according to the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows, Arduino puts the source code for hardware specific stuff in User\AppData\Local\Arduino, and not in the installation folder.

```
/* -------- US_WPMR : (USART Offset: 0xE4) Write Protect Mode Register -------- */
#define US_WPMR_WPEN (0x1u << 0) /**< \brief (US_WPMR) Write Protect Enable */
#define US_WPMR_WPKEY_Pos 8
#define US_WPMR_WPKEY_Msk (0xffffffu << US_WPMR_WPKEY_Pos) /**< \brief (US_WPMR) Write Protect KEY */
#define US_WPMR_WPKEY(value) ((US_WPMR_WPKEY_Msk & ((value) << US_WPMR_WPKEY_Pos)))
```

I would guess unlocking / locking would take the format:

```
????->US_WPMR = (US_WPMR_WPEN | US_WPMR_WPKEY(0x555341));
????->US_WPMR = (~US_WPMR_WPEN & US_WPMR_WPKEY(0x555341));
```